Is it possible do 'Allow Lauching' for .desktop file
After installation application every time I must do 'Allow Lauching' for .desktop file that it appears on the Desktop. As I understood it's equals to execute several commands from this answer - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218954/desktop-files-allow-launching-set-this-via-cli. Maybe install4j has some ready solution for this case or it must be a bash script after installation?

As of install4j 10.x, this is not implemented, but this will be automatically done starting with install4j 11.0 later this year.
